# Speed performance of function calls using class pointers vs boost::function?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, boost

**Background:**

I have some code that implements a Genetic Algorithm and I am currently testing out an idea. In this idea, I need to switch out how the algorithm executes at each step by calling one of several possible functions. For example, inside the algorithm there is a step called "Mating" for which academic researchers have developed numerous approaches. A very short list of possible options could be:

- Simulated Binary Crossover
- Fixed Crossover
- Dynamic Crossover

Each of these options have their own class with a common interface derived from a base class. By doing this I am able to implement a wide variety of behaviors when accessing the common *mate()* functionality.

I see two options before me on how I could call a given *mate()* function.

1. Keep a container of pointers to the various instances and then call the desired method through that reference.
2. Use boost::bind and boost::function to directly reference the needed function without going through the class pointer call at run time.

**Question:**

Is there any kind of performance hit I would take by using one over the other? I don't know enough of what goes on in the background to make an educated guess on the matter, but I'm rather curious if there is any fundamental difference.

Comment: Option 1 is going to be faster, but if the function call only happens once in a while option 2 is most likely fine too. If you are using c++11 or newer you have `std::bind` and `std::function` too.

Comment: _"I don't know enough of what goes on in the background to make an educated guess on the matter"_, why don't you just benchmark? And you should probably look into lambdas and `std::function`

Comment: @super I don't think you can say that. If it's a single-function interface I basically expect both to have exactly the same performance, although it could be better if the instance on which a member is being invoked is constant through many invocations. Then again, inlining gives compilers huge opportunity for similar optimizations with `function<>`. The point is: 1. code intentfully 2. profile 3. optimize later

Comment: @sehe You might be right. But I think it's reasonable to point out that compilers generally have an [easier time optimizing](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html) known objects compared to type-erased wrappers.

Comment: @PasserBy I could, and am going to do that, but it wouldn't really teach me much of anything. I was more of going for the "why" more than anything else.